# Explanation type on discrete-mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have all this `C(n,r),C(n+r-1,r),P(n,r),P(n+r-1,r)`.I know a lot about it but sometimes i confusing.When it says *at least one time* ,when says with not care which goes first(i think we use the p(n+r-1,r).Can you somehow make me one example for each one?Some type are same example P(n,r) or C(n,r) but C(n,r) is "same" and the P(n,r) is distinct.May , the words "same" or distinct isn't the proper its not my nature language but i hope you catch me.Anyway,i would like to give me an good example for each.I know r and n what it is.r lets say is the balls and n the slots.I want explanation for each nothing else.

Comment: [This](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) page here talks a lot about permutations and combinations, and in each case also talks about order mattering vs order not mattering. I can't personally say I've seen P(n+r-1,r) ever used though.

Comment: thanks a lot it seems good